# move data in bulk from oracle to SQL database

Tags: sql-server

Would like to know which is the best way to move data in bulk from oracle to SQL database programmatically in VB.NET application.This application is suppose to run continuously and moves data from Oracle to SQL whenever data comes.

I have found OPENDATASOURCE but does not know the exact syntax.

Can someone help me out.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Check SQL Server 2008 Books Online ***OPENDATASOURCE*** which then leads to **sp_addlinkedserver**.

Those two items should help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I used SQLBulkcopy feature of VS2008 that made by work a lot  more faster.